# Drawing a tile based map

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

This script draws the controls, hero, surface and the map:

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Drawable myImage;

        int tileWidth = 50;
        int tileHeight = 50;

        int rowBaseX = 0;
        int rowBaseY = 0;

        int[][] board = new int[][] {
                {0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
                {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
                };
        int mapWidth = 10;
        int mapHeight = 10;

        for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++)
        {

        for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++)
        {
        Resources res = this.getContext().getResources();

        switch(board[row][col])
        {
        case 0:
        myImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tile1);
        break;
        case 1:
        myImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tile2);
        break;
        default:
        myImage = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tile3);
        break;
        }

        int curL = rowBaseX + (col * tileWidth);
        int curU = rowBaseY + (row * tileHeight);
        int curR = curL + tileWidth;
        int curD = curU + tileHeight;

        myImage.setBounds(curL,curU,curR,curD);
        myImage.draw(canvas);
        }
        }

        droid.draw(canvas);
        butt.draw(canvas);
        butt1.draw(canvas);
        butt2.draw(canvas);
        butt3.draw(canvas);
        buttz.draw(canvas);
        buttz1.draw(canvas);
        buttz2.draw(canvas);
        buttz3.draw(canvas);
        buttx.draw(canvas);
    }
```

There is a hero, which has to be redrawn when player moves him with the controls, and all other drawables also has to be redrawn. The problem is that drawing a map is a long process, so the bigger map i create, the slower hero moves, because every tile of the map has to be painted. Is there a way to put all the tiles to a one bitmap in other method and draw that one bitmap in the canvas method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to only draw the portion of your map that is visible on the screen.  That way no matter how big the overall map becomes the drawing of that map is always constant.  Since you're on a grid system you can easily figure out which cell the hero is in:

```
heroGridX = hero.x % mapWidth;
heroGridY = hero.y % mapHeight;
```

From there you can calculate how many cells around the player you want to draw by using the width and height of the canvas and the constant size of your grid cell's width and height:

```
leftGrid = heroGridX - (canvas.getWidth() / tileWidth) / 2;
topGrid = heroGridY - (canvas.getHeight() / tileHeight) / 2;
rightGrid = heroGridX + (canvas.getWidth() / tileWidth) / 2;
bottomGrid = heroGridY + (canvas.getHeight() / tileHeight) / 2;
```

You could use a data structure to store these values independent of the hero and only move them once the player gets close to an edge to scroll the map.  That way the hero moves up and down without scrolling the map until they get X or Y pixels to the edge of a tile.  Instead of calculating these inside the rendering routine.

This will use far less memory than drawing the entire map into one large bitmap.  Drawing into a large bitmap is trading more memory usage for less CPU time.  As your map grows larger so does the memory needed to draw that map.  This algorithm merely keeps drawing the map a constant because the size of your screen doesn't change at runtime.  And, in comparison to the other option your memory usage doesn't grow any larger as your map grows larger (it grows very small in comparison to drawing more tiles in a canvas).  One important fact about this is that if you did get a larger screen (say a tablet vs a phone).  This algorithm will scale up properly too so the player will see more of the surrounding terrain of the map.

Answer (score 3):

If creating a static map outside your application is not an option, you could separate the drawing of static content from the dynamic content.

Create a `Bitmap`, create a `Canvas` with it and draw your map on that `Canvas`. You only need to do this once. Render the dynamic content once per frame on another `Canvas`.
Then draw both `Bitmap`s on the "real" `Canvas` of your `SurfaceView`. It could look like this :

the once-per-map part :

```
Bitmap mapBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, myConfig);
Canvas c = new Canvas(mapBitmap);
//draw map on c
```

...and the once-per-frame part:

```
//draw dynamic stuff    
Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawBitmap(mapBitmap, null, targetRect, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(heroBitmap, null, targetRect, null);
    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost();
```

**EDIT:**

You draw your tiles like you used to with `myImage.draw(canvas)`, but passing the mapBitmap-`Canvas` as argument instead of your "real" canvas. `myConfig` has to be a [Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html). Take the `RGB_565` as it is the internal format.

Comment: but how can i put my map tiles into the mapBitmap? I have to write somethin istead of myConfig?

Comment: @Liukas I have edited the answer to include it. I hope it makes the matter clearer.
`

Comment: sorry but i used another solution. You can help me on other question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717038/tile-based-map-scrolling

Comment: @Liukas - sure, as chubbard said it's a tradeoff between CPU time and RAM. chubbard's solution is better for maps that are much bigger than the screen and unlike mine, it is suited for dynamic maps too. My solution is much faster, but unpractical once your maps get bigger.

Comment: i dont say your solution is bad ;) Anyway i need the fastest solution for big maps, because chubbards's solutions is still to slow... :/