# Drawing a scrollable tiled background

Tags: android, background-image, tiles, scrollable

I'm developing a game where the background is drawn using tiles, there are about 100 tiles in it. The background should also be scrollable. Problem is that it won't scroll smoothly, there is not enough time to update the coordinates of every tile and redraw it, so I observe some unwanted visual effects. Is there any way to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715159/drawing-a-tile-based-map/8715414#8715414

Comment: By 'unwanted visual effects', do you mean the screen isn't updating fast enough so the scrolling looks choppy?

Comment: @SteveBlackwell, Actually, the scrolling is smooth enough, but the tiles do not catch to be redrawn on right places on every scrolling move.

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks like this:

```
screenL = 0;
screenR = screenWidth;
screenU = 0;
screenD = screenHeight;
curL = tileX + tileWidth;
curR = tileX;
curU = tileY;
curD = tileY + tileHeight;


if (screenL < curR & screenR > curL) {
            if (screenU < curD & screenD > curU) {
        tile.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
```

If you dont know how to get the width and height of the mobile phone screen, let me know. You could also write your tile map engine script.

Comment: Sorry, but what hero are you talking about? Did you read my question properly?