# java swing real-time using revalidate and repaint

Tags: java, swing

I am sorry about my english skills

I want to show real-time view of moving using revalidate and repaint in roop

What should i do?

Help me~~

```
void G_PRINT_MAP()
{

    System.out.println("[G_PRINT_MAP] x is "+x+"  y is"+y);

    this.MAP_PANEL = new JPanel( new GridLayout(this.MAP.length, this.MAP.length) ); //패널설정

    for(int i=0; i<this.MAP.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<this.MAP.length; j++)
        {
            if((i==x && j==y) && MAP[i][j] == 3)
            {
                //함정밟았을
                System.exit(0);//프로그램종료 
            }
            else if(i==x && j==y)
            {
                this.MAP_PANEL.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./image/me.png")));
                System.out.println("x is "+x+" y is "+y);
            }
            else if(i==(MAP.length-1) && j==(MAP.length-1))
            {
                this.MAP_PANEL.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("./image/bread.png")));
            }
        }
    }

    MIRO_FRAME.add(this.MAP_PANEL);

    //실시간으로 보이기위해서 사용 
    this.MAP_PANEL.revalidate();
    this.MAP_PANEL.repaint();
}


public int G_AUTO_GAME(int x, int y)
{
    int RAND_CHECK[]={0,0,0,0};
    int RESULT = -1;
    int SAVE_VALUE=-1;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j>10; j++)
        {

            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            G_PRINT_MAP();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715159/drawing-a-tile-based-map). It tells you how to draw a tile-based map in Java (Android, not Swing though) effectively.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Also, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for faster help.

Comment: You could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050723/java-applet-game-2d-window-scrolling/16052048#16052048) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138363/infinite-background-for-game/16138735#16138735)

Comment: *"repaint in roop"*  Roop?  Can you think of another word for that?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than *replacing* components, as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513), think in terms of updating the *content* of a component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).